# how to parse id from php page to html-jquery page via jsonp

Tags: php, jsonp

I have problem to get jsonp from my server by id.
I am sure that my php is good, but i don't know how to parse id from php server to htlm-jquery.

**My php page is:**

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

include 'config.php';

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$id=$_GET['id'];

$sql = "select * from ios where id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$records[] = $row;

}

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';

////////////////////
?>
```

And this works great, i got json object by id in php. 
You can check for example http://www.dr-trkuljic.com/tekst.php?id=1 (you can try with id 2, 3, and 4) you will get result.

But i don't know how to parse that in jquery in my html page

**I am using this in my html page:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var output = $('.nesa');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.dr-trkuljic.com/tekst.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: 'id',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 

                //var ispisi = '<li>' + item.naziv + '</li>' ;

                var ispisi = item.naziv + item.tekst;


                output.append(ispisi);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });
});
```

So, my question is how to parse (show) by id in my html page?
**To be precise how that result from my server http://www.dr-trkuljic.com/tekst.php?id=1 get in my html page?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1 If you are on the same domain

In php change

```
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
```

to

```
echo json_encode($records);
```

JS success:

```
success: function(data, status){

    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    var total = jsonData.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < total; ++i){
        var ispis = jsonData[i].naziv + " " + jsonData[i]item.tekst;
        console.log("My ispis ", ispis);
    }
}
```

2 if you want to use JSONP. (get response from another domain or phonegapp )

When you need a response from another domain you can't use AJAX request, what you can do is load a new script in document for example in  tag, You load that script as js script with your response. Inside that js script you put your response in some variable, and also you can call some function that is defined in already loaded js file. for example

```
echo "var myVar = " . json_encode($records) . '; myCallbackFunc();';
```

Than load that file as js file to your document
and somewhere in that or where ever js that you want to get response - myVar will contain your response that you can use, and when response load your callback function will be called

```
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.src= 'http://www.dr-trkuljic.com/tekst.php?id=1';
head.appendChild(script);

function myCallbackFunc(){
    // Do something with myVar

    var total = myVar.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < total; ++i){
        var ispis = myVar[i].naziv + " " + myVar[i]item.tekst;
        console.log("My ispis ", ispis);
    }
}
```

*EDIT*

Just double check if server response - javascript syntax is ok.

Comment: i am not on same domain. I am trying to build phonegap app, so my html is not on same domain and i need to use jsonp. I didn't quite understand what you write. Could you write me what goes in html file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**As I felt my previous answer was incorrect, allow me to edit:**

After you remove the '(' and ')' from around the json array, you can simply use this quick and easy shorthand format for your jQuery http call: (all parsing is already performed because of the Content-Type header). You are then free to access the appropriate properties of the object.

For further examples on how to use jQuery's $.get() and $.post(), etc... visit this link:
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var output = $('.nesa');
    var idNumber = 1;

    $.get('http://www.dr-trkuljic.com/tekst.php', {id: idNumber}, function(data, status){
        $.each(data, function(i,item){ 

            //var ispisi = '<li>' + item.naziv + '</li>' ;

            var ispisi = item.naziv + item.tekst;

            output.append(ispisi);
        });
    }).fail(function(){
       output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
    });
});
```

To overcome cross-domain errors, you can send this header in your php file with the appropriate url of where you're working from:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your-domain-or-localhost");
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. Could you please suggest me example how to do that, i am really not familiar with jquery. Thanks

Comment: To start out with, apparently you have an error in your json from your php file. I am coming up with a parse error because your json array is surrounded with a set of parenthesis: i.e. ([{}]). This should start and end with just the square brackets: [].

Comment: Thank you again for trying to help me. With this example i got Cross-Origin Request Blocked, because i am trying to connect with my local machine to my server. I am using this tutorial for this: http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/updated-loading-data-in-phonegap-using-jquery-1-5/   Also i can't use id:1, because in that way i would limit query just to 1. I need something that when i click id=1 get 1, or id=1000 get 1000 and so on. Do you have any idea what to do? Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a variable replacing the id#. I'll leave it up to you to determine how the variable is assigned, but that should get you going. As for the cross-origin requests, I have added an example header to be placed in your php file to be sent back to your browser. Also, you can achieve this by looking into the  .httaccess file on your server to allow cross-domain requests.